# EmberJS: Set environment variables in index.html

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We have an Ember (3.5) application. For technical reasons we need environment variables to be set on page load, as opposed to build time. We're trying to set them in `index.html` the following way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {{content-for "head"}}
    <script type="application/javascript">
      // Object.assign polyfill
      Object.assign||Object.defineProperty(Object,"assign",{enumerable:!1,configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:function(e,r){"use strict";if(null==e)throw new TypeError("Cannot convert first argument to object");for(var t=Object(e),n=1;n<arguments.length;n++){var o=arguments[n];if(null!=o)for(var a=Object.keys(Object(o)),c=0,b=a.length;c<b;c++){var i=a[c],l=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,i);void 0!==l&&l.enumerable&&(t[i]=o[i])}}return t}});
      window.env = {};

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', '/api/frontend_settings', true);
      request.send(null);

      request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
        if (request.status === 200) {
          if (request.readyState === 4) {
            Object.assign(window.env, JSON.parse(request.response).settings);
          }
        }
      }, false);
    </script>

    <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.css">
    <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/app-frontend.css">

    {{content-for "head-footer"}}
  </head>
  <body>
    <script integrity="" src="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script integrity="" src="{{rootURL}}assets/app-frontend.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

We added a script which makes a request to some endpoint (`/api/frontend_env_vars`) in the snippet. This endpoint responds with a JSON with the key-values of environment variables which we then assign to `window.env`.

The problem we have is that sometimes Ember scripts load before the variables have been assigned (since we do a request that takes some time to complete), which makes the application crash.

We tried the following alteration to the script, but it didn't work (the error was different, though):

```html
<script type="application/javascript">
  // Object.assign polyfill
  Object.assign||Object.defineProperty(Object,"assign",{enumerable:!1,configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:function(e,r){"use strict";if(null==e)throw new TypeError("Cannot convert first argument to object");for(var t=Object(e),n=1;n<arguments.length;n++){var o=arguments[n];if(null!=o)for(var a=Object.keys(Object(o)),c=0,b=a.length;c<b;c++){var i=a[c],l=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,i);void 0!==l&&l.enumerable&&(t[i]=o[i])}}return t}});
  window.env = {};
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '/api/frontend_env_vars', true);
  request.send(null);
  function loadScript(src) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    document.body.append(script);
  }
  request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
        Object.assign(window.env, JSON.parse(request.response).settings);
        loadScript('assets/vendor.js');
        loadScript('assets/app-frontend.js');
      }
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this in an ember initializer? There you can [`deferReadiness`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Application/methods/deferReadiness?anchor=deferReadiness).

Comment: However, depending on your Problem neither will work. Some environment variables are used during *build time* so setting them an page load is far to late. But it all depends on which environment variables you want to set.

Comment: @Lux your suggestion (initializer with `deferReadiness` usage) actually works, if you create the answer, I'll mark it as the correct one

Comment: Do you really need to do this before the Ember application loads? Why? Can you describe the use case? In most cases just doing the request in Application.beforeModel or an initializer is early enough.

Answer (score 1):

We accomplish this using [ember-cli-server-variables](https://github.com/blimmer/ember-cli-server-variables)

Which allows you to define variables in `index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name='your-app-token' content='example:app:token'>
    <meta name='your-app-user-location' content='Denver'>
    <meta name='your-app-json-data' content='{"foo":"bar"}'>
  </head>
</html>
```

and then access them from the application.

We build our `index.html` [on the server](https://github.com/ilios/ilios/blob/master/templates/index/webindex.html.twig#L24-L26) with the needed variables to there is no async needed to fetch them.